# How to ask for optional Facebook permissions

Tags: facebook, permissions

We use Facebook Connect on our web site. We have some mandatory and some optional permissions. Is it possible to get FB to display a check box next to the optional ones? I've seen some sites that do this but maybe they are displaying their own dialog.

Once an optional permission has been granted, what is the best way to allow the user to revoke just it?

We are using the Javascript SDK but could also implement something in PHP if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the "Improved Auth Dialog" which Facebook will automatically switch all apps over to on 2/15. You can opt-in now through your app settings so you can make sure everything works. After 2/15 you can opt-out, but only until 3/1. The improved dialog shows a second screen of "optional" permissions.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/633/

Users can remove permission at any time by going into their "Privacy Settings", then to the "Apps and Websites" section. I think most users have no idea they remove individual privileges from there.

I find the javascript SDK provides a much better user experience than using redirects on the backend with something like PHP.